# select case на SQLite в Android-реализации

Tags: sqlite, android

Поделитесь пожалуйста примером конструкции типа select case-when-then-else-end для Android SQLite? В стандартной спецификации заявлена ее поддержка, но похоже, Android-версия SQLite либо ее непонимает, либо имеет какие-то тонкости в синтаксисе.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT n.* FROM NAME nORDER BY CASE WHEN displayName LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, n.displayname COLLATE NOCASE", null);
```

Comment: Немножко не о том. Интересует case в селекте, а не в order by.